# Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate Installation problem

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am trying to install Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate.
I have installed WinXP SP3 already.
The installation of first component - Microsoft Windows Installer 4.5 itself failed.
Can anybody suggest an solution.
The following error log came:

[01/02/07,10:41:18] VS Scenario: [2] *** Blocking Components exist and must be satisified before continuing to install** 
[01/02/07,10:41:18] VS Scenario: [2] Windows XP Service Pack 3 is required
[01/02/07,10:41:19] VS Scenario: [2]  **End of Blocking Component List ***
[01/02/07,10:41:41] VS Scenario: [2] Failed to pass the Warnings/Blocks checks in CVSScenario::Start()
[01/02/07,11:18:05] Microsoft Windows Installer 4.5 (x86) - Windows XP: [2] CGenericComponent::Install() expects the setup file for Microsoft Windows Installer 4.5 (x86) - Windows XP, but the file failed verification.
[01/02/07,11:18:05] setup.exe: [2] ISetupComponent::Pre/Post/Install() failed in ISetupManager::InternalInstallManager() with HRESULT -2147467259.
[01/02/07,11:18:06] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Windows Installer 4.5 (x86) - Windows XP is not installed.
[01/02/07,11:18:06] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Windows Installer 4.5 Update (x86) - Windows XP was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:18:06] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual F# 2.0 Runtime was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:18:06] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio Macro Tools was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:18:07] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates TFS Object Model (x86) was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:18:07] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates .NET Framework 4 Multi-Targeting Pack was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:18:07] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:18:07] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Web Deployment Tool (x86) was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:18:07] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 2 - Visual Studio 2010 Tools was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:18:07] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 2 was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:18:07] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Silverlight 3 SDK was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:18:07] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime (x86) was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:18:07] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Office Developer Tools (x86) was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:18:07] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Dotfuscator Software Services - Community Edition was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:18:07] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Crystal Reports templates for Visual Studio 2010 was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:18:08] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 (x86) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:18:08] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Visual Studio 2010 Tools for SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:18:08] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Sync Framework Runtime v1.0 (x86) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:18:08] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Sync Services for ADO.NET v2.0 (x86) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:18:08] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Sync Framework Services v1.0 (x86) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:18:08] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Sync Framework SDK v1.0 (x86) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:18:08] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Performance Collection Tools (x86) was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:18:08] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Publishing Wizard 1.4 was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:18:08] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server System CLR Types was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:18:08] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Objects was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:18:09] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express Service Pack 1 (x86) Upgrade was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:18:09] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Data-Tier Application Framework was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:18:09] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Data-Tier Application Project was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:18:09] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Transact-SQL Language Service was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:18:09] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SharePoint Developer Tools was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:18:09] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 ADO.NET Entity Framework Tools was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:18:09] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Help Viewer 1.0 x86 was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:46:03] Microsoft Windows Installer 4.5 (x86) - Windows XP: [2] CGenericComponent::Install() expects the setup file for Microsoft Windows Installer 4.5 (x86) - Windows XP, but the file failed verification.
[01/02/07,11:46:03] setup.exe: [2] ISetupComponent::Pre/Post/Install() failed in ISetupManager::InternalInstallManager() with HRESULT -2147467259.
[01/02/07,11:46:04] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Windows Installer 4.5 (x86) - Windows XP is not installed.
[01/02/07,11:46:04] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Windows Installer 4.5 Update (x86) - Windows XP was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:46:04] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual F# 2.0 Runtime was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:46:04] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio Macro Tools was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:46:04] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates TFS Object Model (x86) was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:46:05] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates .NET Framework 4 Multi-Targeting Pack was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:46:05] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:46:05] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Web Deployment Tool (x86) was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:46:05] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 2 - Visual Studio 2010 Tools was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:46:05] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 2 was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:46:05] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Silverlight 3 SDK was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:46:05] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime (x86) was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:46:05] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Office Developer Tools (x86) was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:46:05] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Dotfuscator Software Services - Community Edition was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:46:05] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Crystal Reports templates for Visual Studio 2010 was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:46:06] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 (x86) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:46:06] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Visual Studio 2010 Tools for SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:46:06] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Sync Framework Runtime v1.0 (x86) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:46:06] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Sync Services for ADO.NET v2.0 (x86) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:46:06] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Sync Framework Services v1.0 (x86) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:46:06] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Sync Framework SDK v1.0 (x86) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:46:06] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Performance Collection Tools (x86) was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:46:06] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Publishing Wizard 1.4 was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:46:06] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server System CLR Types was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:46:07] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Objects was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:46:07] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Data-Tier Application Framework was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:46:07] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Data-Tier Application Project was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:46:07] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Transact-SQL Language Service was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:46:07] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 ADO.NET Entity Framework Tools was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:46:07] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Help Viewer 1.0 x86 was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:49:09] Microsoft Windows Installer 4.5 (x86) - Windows XP: [2] CGenericComponent::Install() expects the setup file for Microsoft Windows Installer 4.5 (x86) - Windows XP, but the file failed verification.
[01/02/07,11:49:09] setup.exe: [2] ISetupComponent::Pre/Post/Install() failed in ISetupManager::InternalInstallManager() with HRESULT -2147467259.
[01/02/07,11:49:10] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Windows Installer 4.5 (x86) - Windows XP is not installed.
[01/02/07,11:49:10] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Windows Installer 4.5 Update (x86) - Windows XP was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:49:10] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual F# 2.0 Runtime was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:49:10] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio Macro Tools was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:49:11] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates TFS Object Model (x86) was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:49:11] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates .NET Framework 4 Multi-Targeting Pack was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:49:11] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:49:11] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Web Deployment Tool (x86) was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:49:11] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 2 - Visual Studio 2010 Tools was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:49:11] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 2 was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:49:11] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Silverlight 3 SDK was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:49:11] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime (x86) was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:49:11] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Crystal Reports templates for Visual Studio 2010 was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:49:11] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 (x86) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:49:11] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Visual Studio 2010 Tools for SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:49:12] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Sync Framework Runtime v1.0 (x86) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:49:12] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Sync Services for ADO.NET v2.0 (x86) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:49:12] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Sync Framework Services v1.0 (x86) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:49:12] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Sync Framework SDK v1.0 (x86) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:49:12] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Performance Collection Tools (x86) was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:49:12] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Publishing Wizard 1.4 was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:49:12] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server System CLR Types was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:49:12] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Objects was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:49:12] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Data-Tier Application Framework was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:49:12] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Data-Tier Application Project was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:49:12] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Transact-SQL Language Service was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:49:13] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 ADO.NET Entity Framework Tools was not attempted to be installed.
[01/02/07,11:49:13] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Help Viewer 1.0 x86 was not attempted to be installed.

Comment: Have you tried installing Microsoft Windows Installer 4.5 separately?